# NSWindow subclass does not draw title bar on second rendering

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm writing some glue GUI code for a scripting language implementation, and need to be able to programmatically create windows and intercept the key and mouse commands on their views. I've subclassed both NSWindow and NSView.

When I open a window for the first time, I get a window with a title bar and controls. If I close this window and open another, the controls and title don't appear in the new window. However, if I click where the controls *should* be, the new window (with invisible controls) still closes.

Is there something I'm doing in my window initialization that could cause this?

```
+ (HMSLWindow*)hmslWindowWithTitle:(NSString *)title frame:(NSRect)frame {
  HMSLWindow* hmslWindow = [[HMSLWindow alloc]
                            initWithContentRect: frame
                            styleMask: NSMiniaturizableWindowMask | NSTitledWindowMask | NSClosableWindowMask
                            backing: NSBackingStoreBuffered
                            defer: YES];

  hmslWindow.title = [title retain];

  [hmslWindow setContentView:[[HMSLView alloc] initWithFrame:frame]];
  hmslWindow.delegate = [[HMSLWindowDelegate alloc] init];
  [hmslWindow cascadeTopLeftFromPoint:NSZeroPoint];
  [hmslWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];

  [[HMSLWindow windowDictionary] setObject:hmslWindow forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:hmslWindow.windowNumber]];

  return hmslWindow;
}

- (void)close {
  [[HMSLWindow windowDictionary]
   removeObjectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:self.windowNumber]];
  [self.contentView autorelease];
  [self.delegate autorelease];
  [self.title autorelease];
  [super close];
}
```

First window:

[image: First window]

Second window (contentView with white background is correct, but the titlebar is now empty):

[image: Second window]

Comment: Does the delegate provide the title? Is is immediately released.

Comment: Does the delegate provide the title? Is is immediately released.

Comment: This is probably a memory management issue.

I suggest:
1 - Use ARC
2 - Think if you really need to subclass NSWindow, from what you said I think you don't have to

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use ARC. The language I'm porting requires a 32-bit build. Currently, the window subclass has a `graphicsContext` variable to keep track of the Quartz context.

Comment: @GuilhermeRambo, does subclassing NSWindow imply particular memory management issues? There are certainly memory issues with my app, but I don't see how that connects with subclassing NSWindow. Added the `-(void)close` method above in case that helps.

Comment: I didn't say that subclassing NSWindow causes memory issues. I'm just curious because your code is a little strange to me. Why do you have a dictionary in your window which holds a reference to the window itself?

Comment: @GuilhermeRambo ah yes, that's a static variable for the class that holds a reference to every existing window, so that the language I'm gluing to can programmatically control them. I admit that part is pretty hacky as it is.